# Error after installing spacy package

Tags: windows-10, python, python3

I installed spacy package in python 3.6 but after installing I get this error when I want to import this package.

```
In [1]: import spacy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c080f6458562> in <module>()
----> 1 import spacy

C:\Users\Dsaad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>()
      2 from __future__ import unicode_literals
      3
----> 4 from . import util
      5 from .deprecated import resolve_model_name
      6 from .cli import info

C:\Users\Dsaad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in <module>()
      3
      4 import ujson
----> 5 import regex as re
      6 from pathlib import Path
      7 import sys

C:\Users\Dsaad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\regex.py in <module>()
    392 # Internals.
    393
--> 394 import _regex_core
    395 import _regex
    396 from threading import RLock as _RLock

C:\Users\Dsaad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_regex_core.py in <module>()
     19 from collections import defaultdict
     20
---> 21 import _regex
     22
     23 __all__ = ["A", "ASCII", "B", "BESTMATCH", "D", "DEBUG", "E", "ENHANCEMATCH",

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue as well, but it was fixed after I created a [conda environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-a-separate-environment) and specified *python=3*.

> conda create --name py36 python=3

This command installed a few new packages:

- pip: 9.0.1-py36_1
- python: 3.6.1-0
- setuptools: 27.2.0-py36_1
- vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-0
- wheel: 0.29.0-py36_0

I suspect the installation of *vs2015_runtime* is what fixed this issue, but I haven't done a root cause analysis. Visual Studio is mentioned in the [Spacy Windows installation section](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/#source-windows).

Also note if you use this solution you will need to activate the conda environment whenever you want to use it. (see conda envs activating environments docs)

Comment: I've done all of that and I still have the problem.